# Drawing dots between two elements using background pic

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to draw a dotted line between some of my elements without success; I'm trying to accomplish something like the following:

[image: result]
I've looked at a few tutorials to write a line between the elements using the  `::after` pseudo-element, but I don't see anything happening.

```css
.container {
  width: 1066px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.services {
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 1080px;
  padding: 80px 0;
  position: relative;
}

.services .step {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 152px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 50px;
  vertical-align: text-top;
}

.services .step .first {
  float: right;
}

.services .icons {
  background: url("https://www.icracked.com/themes/icracked/images/steps-line.png") repeat-x;
}
```

```html
<div class="services container">
  <div class="step first">
    <strong>PASO 1</strong>
    <br>
    <p>Pon el codigo postal donde te encuentres</p>
  </div>
  <div class="step">
    <strong>PASO 2</strong>
    <br>
    <p>Dinos qual es el problema</p>
  </div>
  <div class="step">
    <STRONG>PASO 3</STRONG>
    <br>
    <p>Relajate, nuestro tecnico esta de camino</p>
  </div>
  <div class="step last">
    <STRONG>PASO 4</STRONG>
    <br>
    <p>Voilà! En menos de una hora tienes el movil arreglado!</p>
  </div>
  <div class="icons">
    <div class="step first">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50" alt="" height="50" width="50"></div>
    <div class="step">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50" alt="" height="50" width="50"></div>
    <div class="step">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50" alt="" height="50" width="50"></div>
    <div class="step last">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50" alt="" height="50" width="50"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zhpmahnq/187/

Comment: Are we able to adjust your HTML, or is that set in stone at this point?

Answer (score 1):

You could try using `display: flex;` and creating a dotted border on only the top or bottom of a span between images.

```
.wrapper {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between; /* not necessary */
}

.dots {
  border-top: 1px dotted black;
  width: 100%;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zhpmahnq/191/